# Bitrise flutter build keeps using older versions of flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart, bitrise

I have a flutter app that I am trying to build through bitrise.

I keep getting a tonne of errors along the lines of

```
Error: The 'super-parameters' language feature is disabled for this library.
    Try removing the package language version or setting the language version to 2.17 or higher.
    super.key
```

and it is blocking me from analyzing and building the app.

Now the issue is, I am using flutter install with upgrade set to true , and have sdk target in my `pubspec.yaml` as

Environment:

> sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"

[image: result of flutter install]

I disabled the caching steps, and tried to create a new deployment pipeline, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

In your workflow, add `Flutter Install`, Then set your desired flutter version on `Input Variables` sections's `Flutter SDK git repository version` field. e.g. 2.8.0.

Comment: tried that, still same issue. I submitted a ticket for bitrise support.